# D3D11 - How to deal with SLI and Nvidia Surround?

Tags: nvidia, direct3d11, dxgi, surround, sli

Is it needed to worry about Nvidia SLI with or without Surround while enumerating adapters and outputs?
Assume a fictional build:

- (2x) GTX 960 in SLI
- (3X) 1920x1080 displays attached in landscape mode by Surround, yielding 5760x1080

While using `IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters` to enumerate adapters, does it show two of the GPUs as separate adapters or just one combined? (assuming SLI is enabled and we occluded any integrated GPUs and Microsoft Basic Render Driver). Same case for Outputs, while using `IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs`, does it return 3 distinct outputs or just one? (assuming Surround is enabled). If it returns only one, `IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList` will include atleast one display mode that is 5760x1080, prove me right or wrong. But if it is three distinct outputs, should I create one swapchain per output?

*Notes:*

- *[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309100/nvidia-sli-tricks) doesn't answer my question properly*
- *I don't want any NvAPI based approach, just pure Directx11*
- *The [Surround Best Practices](https://developer.nvidia.com/3d-vision-and-surround-technology) doesn't give much information*
- *I currently don't have any SLI+Surround setup so I can't answer my own question. And I have to deal with AMD Eyefinity as well*

Comment: All SLI adapters will be reported as a single adapter while `EnumOutputs` will return 3 distinct outputs (so you'll have to create 3 swap chains and so on). Surround is just a marketing buzzword.

Comment: Oh shoot, that's just plain bad. I thought that there'll be one whole output.